# myth-auth bug when integrated with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

So, it seems like there is a bug in myth-auth when integrated with codeigniter.

It tries to authenticate the `$password` even when the  `$email` is null.Therefore throwing the `Undefined offset: 1` exception.

Here in `APPPATH\ThirdParty\myth-auth\src\Authentication\Passwords\NothingPersonalValidator.php` on line 91

```
84         // Use the pieces as needles and haystacks and look every which way for matches.
85         if($valid)
86         {
87             // Take username apart for use as search needles
88             $needles = $this->strip_explode($userName);
89 
90             // extract local-part and domain parts from email as separate needles
91****             [$localPart, $domain] = \explode('@', $email);
92             // might be john.doe@example.com and we want all the needles we can get
93             $emailParts = $this->strip_explode($localPart);
94             if( ! empty($domain))
95             {
96                 $emailParts[] = $domain;
97             }
98             $needles = \array_merge($needles, $emailParts);
```

That exception is always thrown whenever the email field is left empty, rather than it redirecting back with the

> 'Email is left empty'

error message

Comment: There exists no Codeigniter myth-auth bug as myth-auth is not part of CI. There might be a bug in your code or eventually even in the myth-auth library.

Comment: @Vickel I really dont get your point

Comment: after line 73, add this line :  if(!$email) $valid = false;

Answer (score 0):

So, for now I am using a *really bad hack* and editing the system file at `myth-auth\src\AuthController` line 180...

```
$rules_part1 = [
        'username'      => 'required|alpha_numeric_space|min_length[3]|is_unique[users.username]',
        'email'         => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
    
    ];

    if (! $this->validate($rules_part1))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', service('validation')->getErrors());
    }

    $rules_part2 = [
        'password'      => 'required|strong_password',
        'pass_confirm'  => 'required|matches[password]',
    ];

    if (! $this->validate($rules_part2))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', service('validation')->getErrors());
    }
```